# make: g++: Command not found make: Error 127

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Preciso executar um arquivo que necessita do comando `make`. Quando digito esse comando ocorre o erro:

> make: g++: Command not found make: *** [clearlines] Error 127

Já executei os comandos:

```
# cd /var/lib/dpkg/info/
# ls | grep "install-info"
```

Também executei os comandos abaixo para resolver os problemas do pacote 
`install-info`.

```
# rm install-info*
# apt-get install -f
# dpkg --configure -a
```

Infelizmente, continuo não conseguindo executar o comando `make`.

Answer (score 5):

O `sudo apt-get -y install build-essential` funcionou e ajeitou a situação para mim.

Nota: O pacote build-essential contém uma lista de pacotes necessários para criar um pacote Debian (DEB). Esses pacotes são libc, gcc, g++, make, dpkg-dev etc. O pacote build-essential contém os pacotes necessários como dependências, portanto, quando você instala o build-essential, instala todos os pacotes em um único comando.
Vale dizer que ele funcionou por conter o g++, contudo tem algumas ferramentas de desenvolvimento, mas não todas.

Comment: Funcionou. Uma pequena descrição sobre o que é esse pacote seria bem-vinda e agregaria na resposta. :)

Answer (score 3):

Digite no terninal

```
     sudo apt-get -y install build-essential
```

tecle ENTER

Talvez seja necessário instalar o g++ à parte

```
     sudo apt-get -y install g++
```

tecle ENTER

Talvez seja necessário instalar o make à parte

```
     sudo apt-get -y install make
```

Comment: Digitei o comando acima e obtive como resposta:

Comment: Infelizmente obtive a seguinte mensagem: Impossível encontrar o pacote build-essential

Comment: O g++ já está instalado, pois não tive pacotes autalizados e nenhum novo pacote instalado. Sigo sem conseguir executar o comando make.

Comment: Tive como resposta: make já é a versão mais nova.

Comment: Então seu makefile está com erro. Aliás, o que é aquele tal de "clearlines" que aparece na mensagem de erro ?

Comment: clearlines é o nome do arquivo executável que eu preciso rodar utilizando o comando make.

Comment: Pois então, o make não está achando esse tal de clearlines...tente adicionar ao PATH e veja se resolve.